# Portably retrieve Subversion 1.7 revision in PHP?

Tags: php, svn

In Subversion 1.6, there was an `.svn` directory in every working copy directory. I could use the following code to quickly retrive the current revision number without the need for shell access/execution.

```
public function getSubversionRevision() {
    if(file_exists("../.svn/entries")) {
        $svn = File("../.svn/entries");
        return (int)$svn[3];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Subversion 1.7 breaks this code. There is now only one `.svn` directory per local repository. There *is* an `entries` file in this directory but it no longer has anything useful for me. It looks like everything I need is now in a SQLite database. Specifically `wc.db`. I suppose I could use PHP's SQLite functions to get the info I need, but this sounds a little too expensive to run on every (or close to every) page load.

Any ideas? Breaking out the `exec` function and hoping that Subversion binaries are installed (and in the $PATH!) is a last resort. To summarize, I need to find a way to locate the `.svn` directory at the root of the repository (which could be different depending on your checkout location) and then somehow parse a file in there (probably `wc.db`) in a cost-effective way.

Comment: Linux is the target OS. The goal is to make the code as portable as possible, to the point where the operating system and the specific configuration of that OS is irrelevant to the greatest extent possible.

Comment: I do not see much use of portability here from OS to OS. if you are trying to do it for Linux, you can write a script to `svn update` for you every time, and scrap the revision number from the update's output into a file.

`svn --non-interactive update ..` then
`svn --non-interactive update .. | perl -p -e "s/.* revision ([\d]*)\./\$1/" > ../version.phtml;`

Comment: That's probably the best I can do until the svn pecl library is patched to work with 1.7.

Comment: In that case, I have put my solution as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script to `svn update` for you every time, and scrap the revision number from the update's output into a file. The following bash script should more or less do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

svn --non-interactive update .. 
svn --non-interactive update .. | perl -p -e "s/.* revision ([\d]*)\./\$1/" > ../version.phtml;
```

Comment: This is what I'll have to do until the PECL SVN library is patched to work with Subversion 1.7. In my particular use case, I don't need the auto-updating. I'm keeping the original 1.6 code intact and using the shell execution as a fallback (essentially if it's not 1.6 then try the shell command).

Answer (score 2):

try using a SVN library [SVN](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) as it will give you access to repository information and more functionality over SVN repository.
Take a look at function [svn_status](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-status.php) you will receive and array of svn repository information

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [path] => /home/bob/wc/sandwich.txt
        [text_status] => 8 // item was modified
        [repos_text_status] => 1 // no information available, use update
        [prop_status] => 3 // no changes
        [repos_prop_status] => 1 // no information available, use update
        [name] => sandwich.txt
        [url] => http://www.example.com/svnroot/deli/trunk/sandwich.txt
        [repos] => http://www.example.com/svnroot/
        [revision] => 123 // <-- Current Revision
        //..
    )
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get the PECL SVN library to compile on top of Subversion 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a clumsy (but relatively thorough) implementation of Subversion 1.7 revision retrieval in [TheHostingTool](https://github.com/TheHostingTool/TheHostingTool/commit/fb35e4b61c2d18f166d88aa690fe9391dda536f1). Check the commit message for an explanation. The function is contained in class_main.php which is one directory after /trunk (/trunk/includes/class_main.php). You'll need to adjust relative paths for your specific needs. This is a slightly modified version of the function found in class_main.php for use elsewhere.

```
public function getSubversionRevision() {
    // This will work for Subverson 1.6 clients and below
    if(file_exists("../.svn/entries")) {
        $svn = File("../.svn/entries");
        return (int)$svn[3];
    }
    // Check the previous directories recursively looking for wc.db (Subversion 1.7)
    $searchDepth = 3; // Max search depth
    // Do we have PDO? And do we have the SQLite PDO driver?
    if(!extension_loaded('PDO') || !extension_loaded('pdo_sqlite')) {
        $searchDepth = 0; // Don't even bother...
    }
    for($i = 1; $i <= $searchDepth; $i++) {
        $dotdot .= '../';
        if(!file_exists("$dotdot.svn/wc.db")) {
            continue;
        }
        $wcdb = new PDO("sqlite:$dotdot.svn/wc.db");
        $result = $wcdb->query('SELECT "revision" FROM "NODES" WHERE "repos_path" = "'.basename(realpath('..')).'"');
        return (int)$result->fetchColumn();
    }
    if($this->canRun('exec')) {
        exec('svnversion ' . realpath('..'), $out, $return);
        // For this to work, svnversion must be in your PHP's PATH enviroment variable
        if($return === 0 && $out[0] != "Unversioned directory") {
            return (int)$out[0];
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Instead of `.= '../'` you may want to use str_repeat if you don't start at 1. Or, you could simply define `$dotdot` ahead of time to wherever you would like to start.

Comment: If you want to get the last changed revision number change `SELECT "revision"` to `SELECT "changed_revision"`

Answer (score 0):

Or just query:

```
SELECT "changed_revision" FROM "NODES" ORDER BY changed_revision DESC LIMIT 1;
```

if you wonder the last revision of the whole repo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but if you want portable and bullet-proof solution, why not call Subversion CLI inside PHP?

You can use `svn info` inside any directory of WC (capture, parse output and get a set of data) of `svnversion` if you want to get only global revision

Comment: That's not exactly portable. They could have SVN installed without having it in a PATH that PHP looks in. I did use this option as a backup in my solution.